# Run function after page load but NOT refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**I have a jquery function I want to run ONLY when a page is loaded the first time, *not* after a refresh.**

Here's the code:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
    $("#logo-black").typed({
        strings: ["Nothing^450&Co^250.^500", "^800__^400&Co^600."],
        typeSpeed: 70,
        backSpeed: 100,
    callback: function() {
        $(".typed-cursor").css("display", "none"),
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.main-load').toggleClass('main-load-active'),
            $('.nav-text').toggleClass('nav-text-active');
        },400),
        $('.nav-reveal').toggleClass('nav-reveal-active');
        }
    });
});
```

**A few things to note:** 
-I'm using [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/), so content is added/removed via AJAX.

Code that initializes barba.js for my project:

```
initFullpagePlugin();

function initFullpagePlugin (parentElement) {
var element;

element = parentElement ? $('#fullpage', parentElement) : 
$('#fullpage');

if (element.length) {

  // Destroys old fullPage.js object in memory,
  // removes elements from DOM
  if ($.fn.fullpage.destroy) {
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
  }
  element.fullpage({
    //Scrolling
    autoScrolling:false,
    scrollingSpeed: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    fitToSection: false
  });
}
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
if (!('webkitClipPath' in document.body.style)) {
alert('Sorry, this demo is available just with webkitClipPath. Try with 
Chrome/Safari.');
}

Barba.Pjax.init();
Barba.Prefetch.init();


var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
start: function() {
/**
 * This function is automatically called as soon the Transition starts
 * this.newContainerLoading is a Promise for the loading of the new 
container
 * (Barba.js also comes with an handy Promise polyfill!)
 */

// As soon the loading is finished and the old page is faded out, let's 
fade the new page
Promise
  .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
  .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
},

fadeOut: function() {
/**
 * this.oldContainer is the HTMLElement of the old Container
 */

return $(this.oldContainer).animate({ opacity: 0 }).promise();
},

fadeIn: function() {
/**
 * this.newContainer is the HTMLElement of the new Container
 * At this stage newContainer is on the DOM (inside our #barba-
container and with visibility: hidden)
 * Please note, newContainer is available just after 
newContainerLoading is resolved!
 */
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
var _this = this;
var $el = $(this.newContainer);

$(this.oldContainer).hide();

$el.css({
  visibility : 'visible',
  opacity : 0
});

initFullpagePlugin($el);

$el.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400, function() {
  /**
   * Do not forget to call .done() as soon your transition is finished!
   * .done() will automatically remove from the DOM the old Container
   */
  _this.done();
});
}
});

/**
* Next step, you have to tell Barba to use the new Transition
*/

Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
/**
 * Here you can use your own logic!
 * For example you can use different Transition based on the current 
 page or link...
 */

 return FadeTransition;
 };
});

$('.no-click').on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**For instance**, [this design studio](https://www.wearenation.co.uk/) has an animation that runs when you first load the home page, but *not* after a refresh. (NOTE: this seems to only apply to the mobile version, but it's what I'm trying to achieve. The element I'm animating is present on every page, so making sure it only fires on first load & ONLY on the index.html is something I'm shooting for)

Any help/suggestions/constructive criticism is appreciated!

Comment: animation runs on refresh for me

Comment: You're right! But it doesn't on the mobile version

Comment: It does on my iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code executed on the client is stateless between loads. If you want to remember state from page load to page load, you can either:

- Track the session on the back end.
- Use cookies/local storage in the client's browser.

Comment: Thank you Chase! I'll look further into the documentation for the plugin I'm using

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this from the server side.

Check the [referrer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).  If it is not present, or it is not the same as the URL in the current request, go ahead and emit the jquery function so that it will execute when the page is loaded into the browser. When it is the same as the URL in the current request, just withhold the jquery script so that it can't run.

If the page is 100% static and you can't do anything like this, well, see Chase's answer.

Comment: 100% static is correct, so I'll take Chase's advice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transitionCompleted function to load your script.

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', function(currentStatus, prevStatus) {

    if (prevStatus) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            // call your script

        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

Remember that the barba.js event `transitionCompleted` is fired each time a new page is loaded.